# Switch between active objects - understanding transform/view

Tags: directx, direct3d, mesh

it is something I don't understand on transforming (meshes). Please take a look at my code (which is in Render() function) first:

```
            foreach (GeometricObject obj in this.objects)
            {
                if (obj != this.activeObject)
                {
                    obj.Mesh = MeshUtils.ChangeMeshColor(obj.Mesh, Color.Yellow, device);
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.Mesh = MeshUtils.ChangeMeshColor(obj.Mesh, Color.Green, device);
                    obj.GeometryMatrix.Translate(this.move);
                }
                device.Transform.World = obj.GeometryMatrix;
                obj.Mesh.DrawSubset(0);
            }
```

**Explanation:**
I have got some yellow gometriObjects (meshes) and one green activeObject (I can switch between them by keyboard 1-4). 'move' is a vector that I change after every arrow is selected on keyboard (so I can move the active objects).

BUT it is not working as I wanted to. ...if I change the position of one of my objects...then after switching to the other (changing activeObject) I got the other view on the screen (after all switches ... all objects are in the same place of the screen;/). Why is that it isn't the same view for all the time? I think...it should, because I have got the same view setted:

```
            device.Transform.View = Matrix.LookAtLH(new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, -25.0f), // Camera position
                    new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),   // Look-at point
                    new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));  // Up vector
```

So what's my problem? Any ideas:)?
Aha...the problem isn't connected with that changingMeshColor function...i checked.

Comment: I've read this several times and I still don't know what your question is.  AFAICT the fact that your view matrix never changes but you can change your object positions means that the camera might not be looking at a given object.

Answer (score 0):

Ech....it started to work after changing:

```
obj.GeometryMatrix.Translate(this.move);
```

to:

```
obj.GeometryMatrix *= Matrix.Translation(this.move);
```

...but why is that? I really don't know... Translate() should change my matrix, not set as a translation (as it did)

Comment: In the latter code you are transforming a matrix by the translation matrix defined by "move".  In the former you are creating a translation matrix.  The former overwrites anything that was already in the matrix.